# Why is the point-cloud-library's loadPCDFile so slow?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I am reading 2.2 million points from a PCD file, and `loadPCDFile` is using ca 13 sec both in `Release` as well as `Debug` mode. Given that visualization programs like CloudCompare can read the file in what seems like milliseconds, I expect that I am doing something harder than it needs to be.

What am I doing wrong?

The top of my PCD file:

```
# .PCD v0.7 - Point Cloud Data file format
VERSION 0.7
FIELDS rgb x y z _
SIZE 4 4 4 4 1
TYPE F F F F U
COUNT 1 1 1 1 4
WIDTH 2206753
HEIGHT 1
VIEWPOINT 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
POINTS 2206753
DATA binary
    ¥•ÃöèÝÃájfD        ®§”ÃÍÌÝÃá:fD        H”Ã¸¾ÝÃH!fD   .....
```

From my code, reading the file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <pcl/common/common.h>
#include <pcl/common/common_headers.h>
#include <pcl/common/angles.h>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>
#include <pcl/console/parse.h>
#include <pcl/filters/extract_indices.h>
#include <pcl/features/normal_3d.h>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>

int main() {
    (...)

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr largeCloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
    largeCloud->points.resize(3000000); //Tried to force resizing only once. Did not help much.

    if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZRGB>("MY_POINTS.pcd", *largeCloud) == -1) {
        PCL_ERROR("Couldn't read file MY_POINTS.pcd\n");
        return(-1);
    }

    (...)
    return 0;
}
```

(Using PCL 1.8 and Visual Studio 2015)

Comment: I don't know if important, but I have never called a resize when loading clouds.

Comment: I used that because I wanted to init the cloud big enough so that the load function didn't have to resize the cloud constantly while reading inn data. It did not help, though.

Comment: Are you certain the time is being spent in that load statement and not in the visualizer startup or something?

Comment: Was the pcd file created by pcl?

Comment: are you using a custom point type...? the fields size count and type do not match anything i have in xyzrgb or xyzrgba file types...

Comment: I am very certain that the time is spent in the load function. The file is in fact not produced by pcl, but by CloudCompare. It could be that this introduces some uncertainty. I will have to check if the result differs if i save the file from pcl.

Comment: Not trying to offend, just verifying.  I definitely think it comes down to formatting now, you will either need a custom point type or to have an intermediate step where pcl converts the cloud compare point into the format it likes.

Comment: If you don't have this sorted out by the weekend, I will install cloud compare and try to recreate exactly what you are seeing.

Comment: I do not have access to the pointcloud or my program for some weeks now. I would very much like to accept your answer, so if you would like to test it and report on how it went, I would be grateful. Anyway, thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: Done... pretty sure you aren't engaging pcl release libraries. My reasoning for that explanation is in my answer below. @emilal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary of below...

- PCL is slightly slower at loading cloud compare formatted PCD files.  Looking at the headers, CC seems to add an extra variable to each point "_" that PCL doesn't like and has to format out.  But this is only a difference of 30%-40% load time.
- Based on the result that with the same size point cloud (3M), my computer took 13 seconds to load it from cloud compare when the program was compiled in `Debug` mode and only 0.25s to load the same cloud in `Release` mode. I think that you are running in debug mode. Depending on how you compiled/installed PCL, you may need to rebuild PCL to generate the appropriate `Release` build.  My guess is that whatever you think you are doing to change from `Debug` to `Release` is not in fact engaging the PCL release library.

In PCL, across almost all functions, moving from `Debug` to `Release` will often give you one to two orders of magnitude faster processing (due to PCL's heavy usage of large array objects that have to be managed differently in `Debug` mode for visibility)

---

---

Testing PCL with cloud compare files

Here is the code that I ran to produce the following outputs:

```
std::cout << "Press enter to load cloud compare sample" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();

    TimeStamp stopWatch = TimeStamp();
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr tempCloud2(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
    pcl::io::loadPCDFile("C:/SO/testTorusColor.pcd", *tempCloud2);

    stopWatch.fullStamp(true);
    std::cout <<"Points loaded: "<< tempCloud2->points.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Sample point: " << tempCloud2->points.at(0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Press enter to save cloud in pcl format " << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    pcl::io::savePCDFileBinary("C:/SO/testTorusColorPCLFormatted.pcd", *tempCloud2);

    std::cout << "Press enter to load formatted cloud" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();

    stopWatch = TimeStamp();
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr tempCloud3(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
    pcl::io::loadPCDFile("C:/SO/testTorusColorPCLFormatted.pcd", *tempCloud3);
    stopWatch.fullStamp(true);
    std::cout << "Points loaded: " << tempCloud3->points.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Sample point: " << tempCloud3->points.at(0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
```

Cloud compare generated colored cloud (3M points with color):
[image: cloud compare generated colored cloud (3m points with color)]

Running in `Debug`, reproduced your approximate load time with a 3M pt cloud:

[image: Running in Debug reproduced your approximate load time with a 3M pt cloud]

Running in `Release`:

[image: Running in Release]

Answer (score 1):

I was running into exactly this situation.
It simply comes down to file storage style.  Your file (taking that long to load) is almost certainly an ASCII style point cloud file.  If you want to be able to load it much faster (x100) then convert it to binary format.  For reference, I load a 1M pt cloud in about a quarter second (but that is system dependent)

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tempCloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
```

The load call is the same:

```
pcl::io::loadPCDFile(fp, *tempCloud);
```

but in order to save as binary use this:

```
pcl::io::savePCDFileBinary(fp, *tempCloud);
```

Just in case it helps, here is a snippet of the code I use to load and save clouds (I structure them a bit, but it is likely based on an example, so I don't know how important that is but you may want to play with it if you switch to binary and are still seeing long load times).

```
//save pt cloud
        std::string filePath = getUserInput("Enter file name here");
        int fileType = stoi(getUserInput("0: binary, 1:ascii"));
        if (filePath.size() == 0)
            printf("failed file save!\n");
        else
        {
            pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> tempCloud;
            copyPointCloud(*currentWorkingCloud, tempCloud);
            tempCloud.width = currentWorkingCloud->points.size();
            tempCloud.height = 1;
            tempCloud.is_dense = false;

            filePath = "../PointCloudFiles/" + filePath;
            std::cout << "Cloud saved to:_" << filePath << std::endl;
            if (fileType == 0){pcl::io::savePCDFileBinary(filePath, tempCloud);}
            else
            {pcl::io::savePCDFileASCII(filePath, tempCloud);}
            
        }

//load pt cloud
        std::string filePath = getUserInput("Enter file name here");
        if (filePath.size() == 0)
            printf("failed user input!\n");
        else
        {
            filePath = "../PointCloudFiles/" + filePath;
            pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tempCloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

            if (pcl::io::loadPCDFile(filePath, *tempCloud) == -1) //* load the file
            {
                printf("failed file load!\n");
            }
            else
            {
                copyPointCloud(*tempCloud, *currentWorkingCloud); std::cout << "Cloud loaded from:_" << filePath << std::endl;
            }
        }
```

- List item

Comment: I am quite sure that the pcb file have the data saved binary. ("DATA binary" in the top of the pcb file.)

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct, when comparing with a [pcl example](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/reading_pcd.php). I think the main work of `loadPCDFile` is done in the function `pcl::PCDReader::read`, which is located in the file [pcd_io.cpp](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/io/src/pcd_io.cpp#L678). When checking the code for binary data, as it is in your case, there are [3 nested for loops](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/io/src/pcd_io.cpp#L985) which check if the numerical data of each field is valid. The exact code comment is

```
// Once copied, we need to go over each field and check if it has NaN/Inf values and assign cloud
```

That could be time consuming. However, I am speculating.